# Referencing another project but cannot use it in my current project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two projects within my current solution, one of which is referenced in the other, as you can see in the image.

[image]

I have created a `Controller` in EPOS-DB_API, and am trying to use `using EPOSDataAccess;`, however it comes up with a red squiggly error

> The type or namespace name 'EPOSDataAccess' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have cleaned and rebuilt the project but that made no difference.

Why can I not include this as a using directive?

Comment: First things first - restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Also clear your temp.

Comment: The project name is not necessarily the namespace name. Are you sure you have it right?

Comment: @Archer that didn't change it.

Comment: @CoolJK how do I do that?

Comment: @Crowcoder in the `EPOSDataAccess` properties, the assembly name and default namespace are the same.

Comment: @Harambe, OK that might not be the problem but you can still set a different namespace on classes. The project setting is just the default for the code generator.

Comment: I only see a EDMX model in the first project... Are you sure the generated entity classes are `public` (and not `internal`)?

Comment: Is the project being referenced targetting a higher .net version?

Comment: @bassfader seems like that was the issue! Thanks

Comment: Maybe have a look at which `namespace` you defined for the `Controller` class

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step:

1) Right-click on references in `EPOSDataAccess`

2) Click on Add Reference

3) Search for `EPOSDataAccess`.

4) Then Install